# join two tables without having primary key and foreign key in hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have just run the join query in sql and the query is

SELECT t1.URL,
t1.UPDATED_DATE,
t1.PRIORITY,
t1.NCR_ROW_ID,
t1.ESTIMATED_VALUE,
t1.EQUIPMENT_NAME,
t1.CASE_ID,
t2.CREATED_BY
t2.CREATED_DATE
t2.ESTIMATED_TOTAL
t2.FUNDING_APPROVAL_CATEGORY
t2.NCR_MAIN_CASE_ID
FROM ABC t1
LEFT JOIN BCA t2
on t1.CASE_ID = t2.NCR_MAIN_CASE_ID where t1.PROJECT_ID =1234

Its working fine in SQL but when I tried to run in hibernate its show me the error.
and the table relation is also one to one and there is not any primary and foreign key in both of tables. Could you please anyone help me to solve the problem.

In the ABC class, I have used

```
 @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="NCR_MAIN_CASE_ID") 
private BCA bca;

In the BCA class, I have used
 @OneToOne(mappedBy="bca")
 private ABC abc;
```

but I am getting error"could not resolve property: BCA of"

Comment: `its show me the error` ... what is the error?  If you want to join the two entities, you'll need some kind of relationship between them.

Comment: yes, I implement the one to one relation between them. and I am getting the error.  "Error in getting ABC list from DB : could not resolve property: BCA of"

Comment: As the error clearly says, there is no any property BCA!